# Is this correct to overwrite operator++ in enum_class?

Tags: c++, enums

```
enum class COLOR_
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    YELLOW,
    count
};
inline COLOR_& operator++(COLOR_& c) {
    c = static_cast<COLOR_>(static_cast<std::underlying_type<COLOR_>::type>(c) + 1);
    if (c == COLOR_::count) c = COLOR_::RED;
    return c;
};
```

this code is in my header file. I include that header to use `(COLOR_)++;`in main.cpp. and..

```
Error C2676
binary '++': 'COLOR_' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

this is the error.
Tell me what am I missing or misundertanding.

Comment: You have defined prefix, not postfix operator ++. Try ++COLOR.

Comment: @Eugene oh, that was what am I missing. thank u. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inline COLOR_& operator++(COLOR_& c) { ... }
```

Defines the pre-increment operator (`++someColor`). You can define the post-increment operator like this:

```
inline COLOR_ operator++(COLOR_ &c, int) {
    auto res = c;
    
    ++c;
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The Postfix version is semantically incorrect.

Comment: @Eugene Oh, yes, I see, thanks! Wait a moment.

Comment: @churill thank u. this is what am I missed! : D

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can implement pre and post increment and the wrapping behavior:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

enum class COLOR_
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    YELLOW,
    count
};

// Pre increment
COLOR_& operator++(COLOR_& c) {
    typedef std::underlying_type_t<COLOR_> ut;
    auto constexpr cnt = (ut)COLOR_::count;
    c = COLOR_(((ut)c+1)%cnt);
    return c;
};

// Post increment
COLOR_ operator++(COLOR_& c, int) {
    auto const copy = c;
    ++c;
    return copy;
};

int main() {
    COLOR_ c = COLOR_::RED;
    assert(c++ == COLOR_::RED);
    assert(c == COLOR_::GREEN);
    assert(++c == COLOR_::BLUE);
}
```

Comment: Thank u! more thanks to learn ```assert``` ! this is useful thanks.